# How can I download curses python3.4?

Tags: python, pip, curses

I've installed pip and updated it to the latest version however when I type "pip install curses" into the command prompt I get an reply stating "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for curses"

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: `curses` is a standard Python module.  You shouldn't need to install anything to use it.

Comment: Oh, so it is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) curses that is in question?

Comment: @jasonharper _However_, windows has no equivalent... Something tells me OP is on windows and does not have curses. The answer is, there is no curses.

Comment: So if I'm on windows I cant use curses?

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/vu4hx7yr/curses-2.2-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

See http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses for other versions. Heed the warning: «Unicode characters are not supported.»

Comment: The command you sent didn't work. Once i download the file from the website what do I do please and thanks?

Comment: pip install curses-2.2-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl

Comment: sorry I keep asking I feel im being really stupid "Requirement 'curses-2.2-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist"

Comment: *Once i download the file from the website* — did you download it finally?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: `cd` to the directory where it is and run `pip install` with the name.

Comment: "C:\Users\W Best>pip install D:\curses-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win-amd64.whl
Requirement 'D:\\curses-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win-amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
curses-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win-amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: What platform? 32-bit OS or 32-bit Python? To test yor python run `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`.

Comment: 64 bit, sorry i took so long to reply I fell asleep